# Check and Notify non-existence of Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In a simple windows form application on VS 2010 I have put a ovalShape using power packs.

[The simple Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3aTi.png)

Now automatically this action puts the reference of Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs in to project properties.

when deploying this in different PC obviously the (a)powerpacks needed to be installed if this application doesn't work, (b) or it can set to "copy local = true" in reference properties so that it should sit to next with the application.

assuming (b) is not an option, since it is a solitary executable, (a) is the only option. in this way if the target machine does not have powerpacks the requirement is to notify it to the user in the first place.

apparently the dll will be deployed in when using the "VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup"

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll

so the blind approach is just to check if the above file not exist then prompt user to install "VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup". but i feel its more accurate if the application able to actually check in registry level.

in registry "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks" records in several location, thus makes a confusion.
how to identify the correct key and what should be correct way of checking this reference in vb ?

Comment: *"since it is a solitary executable"*. What does that even mean? There is no such thing. There's just you choosing not to deploy dependencies. Just do it properly and deploy the DLL with your EXE.

Comment: "solitary executable" means a novice tool, so that you can copy this exe to any folder that  you like to work on, and it does the job to the existing files in folder and returns the output to the same folder. this is a user requirement so that its not sitting in one location and portability is key since it is not a commercial software and strictly bound to the nature of usage. I totally agree i make a deploy wizard this can be covered.

Comment: What's not portable about two files? What you do is up to you but it seems ridiculous that forcing the user to install a third-party component is considered a better option than deploying a DLL with the EXE. You could just put both files in a folder and have the EXE work on the parent folder instead. While I've never used it, you may also be able to create a single assembly from the two using ILMerge.

Comment: im on softer side about this dependency, because it is from non other than Microsoft. and there's no argument about the best method of cause bundling it with a setup. if i ask you how to programically identify a dependency would that make it a clear question for you ? also i have seen lot of software's check it dependencies before installation and even download online it within the setup process while not necessarily carrying them in the setup wizard. all i want is just to prompt it without a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try to create an object defined in the dependency and catch the resulting exception.

Handling this you could ask the user to install the package. This is probably not considered good practice but should get the job done.